# Yii2 Pjax Content

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, pjax

Does anyone know how I can re-apply scripts to content loaded via PJAX? e.g. $.pjax.reload({container:'#list'}); works great except now my list not sortable anymore. How do I get the DOM scripts to update for the new content.

Comment: @Tony, I found the pjax:success event after I posted the question yesterday. I'll definitely give this a try. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `pjax:success` event. For example (assuming you have function `initFeatures()` that init your js stuff:

```
function initFeatures() {
    $('#my-selector').widget();
    $('some element').on('click', function(){/*...*/});
    /* and so on...*/
}

$(document).on('pjax:success', function(data, content) {
    initFeatures();
});
```

Using separate function for this kind of stuff is very convenient. Anyway you can re-init your scripts manually if you don't have / don't want to use function approach:

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function(data, content) {
    $('#my-selector').widget();
    /* and so on...*/
});
```

More about pjax events [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax#events)